# Can I make this font have a line width so that it continues on the next line?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress site and I'm using a contact form on this particular page. Each input field has a heading, such as "Name", "Email", etc. It looks great on any desktop browser. But when viewing it from a iphone, the text goes too far and doesn't line up with it's input box. So I tried the following:

```
.page-id-1656 .entry-content-p {
 width:40% !important;
}
```

And that works for the text, but the problem is that shrinks all my other fields. So the input boxes are no longer the size I want them. Is there a way to target only the text?

If this helps, here is the CSS for the input fields:

```
.page-id-1656 .wpcf7-textarea {
   width:40% !important;
   height:100px !important;
   font-size:15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
   border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
   border-color:#adadad !important;
   outline:none !important;
}
```

Or is there a way to use what I tried but make it block out .wpcf7-textarea

EDIT: View source gave me this as the class: wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text

EDIT 2: [Font scaling based on width of container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container) appears to be the answer I'm looking for. I'm leaving the question up as it may be helpful to others. The answer was changing font-size to 1vw instead of 15px. Changing the unit to vw allowed the font to adjust based on the device using it.

Comment: please include the relevant html markup in your question

Comment: It uses contact form 7, I don't have the html.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could sharpen up the CSS styling a bit. I suppose there is some sort of a h1/h2/h3 tag or so in the headings for your form? Something that wraps only the text in the form?

Just use this to make your CSS-styling more accurate:

```
.page-id-1656 .entry-content-p > h3 {
   width: 40% !important;
}
```

Or switch what ever is the case in the h3, but the point here is to specify direct pointers to your CSS-styling. It's hard to say from this point of view what the HTML code looks like in the form and provide you a working piece of code, but you should get pretty far with this.

Edit: Try this

```
.wpcf7 > form > p:first-child {
   width: 40% !important;
}
```

It seems to be a common structure of CF7.

Comment: It's because it's using contact form 7, I don't have the html.

Comment: Could you right click some part of the form and view it with **inspector**? From there you can check the code and provide us some more detailed intel.

Comment: I found this in view source, class=wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-text

Comment: Contact form 7 controls the text and the field. Iphone isn't reading the css for the text part properly. The desktop browsers are.

Comment: I found some sort of a demo of CF7, after a while looking at it, seems like it's a quite simple structure, which may cause some problems here. But try to change the CSS-styling to what I edited on my answer.

Comment: I voted your answer up for the effort you put in, and that it is likely helpful to others, which I appreciate. I found the answer I was looking for. My issue was displaying the font on an iphone, or any mobile device. I never knew about "vw" as font-size units. But when I set the font-size to 1vw !important, it retained the desktop browser font size I wanted and at the same time corrected the mobile browser issue.

Comment: Even I didn't know that, but glad you could figure it out by yourself! Appreciate the upvote!